# How to use multiple Javascript statement conditions with an "OR" confirm

Tags: javascript, if-statement, confirm

I have the following function containing a condition in javascript.

```
function dosomething(id, action) {
    if (action != 'delete' || confirm("Are you sure?")) {
         alert('if action equals delete, then it has been confirmed'); 
         // long lines of code executed here. 
    }
}
```

In the above function condtion, it checks if action is NOT equal to "delete". If its equal delete, it gives a confirmation before proceeding. But I'd like to add another value as well as "delete", where the "Are you sure?" message shows/needs confirmation.

I am unable to do this and I've tried the following.

```
if ((action != 'delete' || action != 'report') || confirm("Are you sure?")) { ...
```

What I am trying to do is, if the action == delete or report, the confirmation message should pop-up.

I don't want to write two different if statements (as shown below), as there is a lot of code that needs to execute after confirmation, and it will be bad practice.

```
if (action != 'delete' || confirm("Are you sure?")) {
```

THEN

```
if (action != 'report' || confirm("Are you sure?")) {
```

THANKS

Comment: `If its equal delete, it gives a confirmation before proceeding` - with your OR condition, this statement is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be clearer to do something like this, reducing indentation and the need for careful reading of the boolean logic:

```
function dosomething(id, action) {
  if (action === 'delete' || action === 'report') {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) return;
  }
  // long lines of code executed here.
}
```

It would be *possible* to write it all in one check like

```
if ((action === 'delete' || action === 'report') && !confirm("Are you sure?")) return;
```

but that's less readable IMO.

Comment: It *will* allow other actions - it simply checks to see if confirmation is needed, and `return`s early if the confirmation is needed *and* if the confirmation fails. In any other situation, including when `action` is something other than `delete` or `report`, `long lines of code executed here` will occur regardless. (This is a kind of inversion of your original code, for the sake of reduced indentation - it's not executing lots of code inside a conditional, it's just returning early if the reverse conditional fails)

Comment: I just read it again. This is exactly what I was looking for :)